# How to take results from a sql query in Java, convert it to a list of strings, then print the result?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, string, object

I'm currently trying to get a list of objects I obtain from a sql query (that gets results from a one row of a db), convert it to a list of strings, then print the result (or print the first item in the array, second, etc)

My code is as follows:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(env.getProperty("buyback-feedback-update"));  


        List<Object[]> d = q.getResultList();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object value : d) {
            if (value instanceof String) {
                String str = (String) value;
                list.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
            }
        }
        String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        System.out.println(array);
```

When I run this code, the terminal log displays as so:

```
Hibernate: select ARBTRT_STATUS_FLAG,ARBTRT_CLOSED_BY_ID,ARBTRT_CLOSING_DT,MODIFY_BY_ID,MODIFY_TIMSTM from arbitration_request ORDER BY MODIFY_TIMSTM DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY

[Ljava.lang.String;@c94526
```

When I run the same query but merely code it so it reads and outputs from list of objects rather then convert to strings, the terminal does print the results from the sql query properly so I know the query works and is getting results just fine. Converting objects to strings is the problem. How can I correct my code to convert objects to strings and print the results as strings?

Comment: Hi there, a few things, this `if (value instanceof String) {` will cause your code to only add to your list whatever is already a string, if that is what you want, ok. Since you already have a List, you don't need to convert to an array and then print the array, just change the last 2 lines of your code to `list.forEach(System.out::println)` Java is natively using the `toString` method of the array object to print it, thats why you are seeing the weird code (object plus hash)

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL query is giving list of array of objects, so you need one nested for-each loop as well. It should look something like below.

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(env.getProperty("buyback-feedback-update"));  


        List<Object[]> d = q.getResultList();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object[] value : d) {
           if (value instanceof String[]) {
              String[] strings = (String[]) value;
              for(String str: strings) {
                 list.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
              }
           }
        }

        list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Running this code doesnt get it to print out the new array of strings though? And doing System.out.print(list) outputs an empty array. How do  I print out the new array of strings that was just converted from the list of objects?

Comment: Since I don't know the query result, I simulated it as below  
        String []strArr = new String[]{"someString1","someString2","someString3"};  
        List<Object[]> d = new ArrayList<>();  
        d.add(strArr);
Its printing all the strings for me. Let me know if my understanding of query results is correct.